# Older book where a slacker is abducted by aliens and trained

Tags: story-identification, books

Trying to remember the name of a book.

It was about a male slacker/loser who is captured by an alien because he won't be missed.
The alien has a machine on his ship that input information directly into his brain.
Things like card tricks, basic wound treatment, karate, and so on.
He is taught all human knowledge and take to an alien world where he is supposed to be a counterbalance to an (protohuman/Neanderthal?) other human who was captured in the far distant past. But the aliens where manipulated by the other human to capture the slacker in the first place (can't remember why).

I read this book in the 80's or 90's.  Please help my faulty memory.   Thanks

Comment: *The Ultimax Man* by Keith Laumer.

Comment: That's it, thank you very much.

Comment: @D.A.V. You're welcome!